# What does the acronym AISAC stand for?

Tags: audio

In CRI ADX2 sound authoring tool, it supports a system called 'AISAC', and there's a blog introducing this system: [Real-time parameter control with AISAC](https://blog.criware.com/index.php/2016/04/05/real-time-parameter-control-with-aisac/), but I can't find any information about the meaning of this word 'AISAC'. Is this word an acronym, and if so what does this acronym stand for?

Comment: According to the _Game Audio Programming_ book by Guy Somberg, it stands for "Advanced Interactive Sound and Active Controller".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [*Game Audio Programming: Principles and Design*](https://books.google.de/books?id=tm0NDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA301&lpg=PA301&dq=%22Advanced+Interactive+Sound+and+Active+Controller%22&source=bl&ots=PiOmZ2gnW1&sig=ACfU3U3eHk65FLld5Clv6cTPNj4H_8LgDg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjhi524mI7hAhXCLFAKHUkaCc8Q6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Advanced%20Interactive%20Sound%20and%20Active%20Controller%22&f=false) by Guy Somberg, AISAC stands for `Advanced Interactive Sound and Active Controller`.

The [free dictionary](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/AISAC) also precises two other meanings that are not relevant in the realm of programming.

Neither of these terms seems to be broadly accepted abbreviations.

Comment: Well, I didn't think about looking at the "free dictionary" as they are not really relevant in terms of audio developpement... Thanks anyway for confirmation.